# Seeking tool to convert GTFS (General Transit Feed Specification) to SHP / KML?

Tags: shapefile, kml, software-recommendations, general-transit-feed-specification

I need to convert GTFS (General Transit Feed Specification https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference), data into some GIS data format like ESRI Shapefile or KML or something else.

Do you know any tool for this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a tool that goes from GTFS to KML:

http://code.google.com/p/googletransitdatafeed/wiki/KMLWriter

and a KML to shape file tool at

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygearth/

For more details please click [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/googletransit/xvP-Q4vYLr0)

Answer (score 1):

[Bob Heitzman's XLS for GTFS](https://sites.google.com/site/rheitzman/) spreadsheet tools can import and export KML, as well as its main function to import and export GTFS feed.

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS Pro 2.2 now provides two tools to create features (shapefile or feature classes) from GTFS data:

- [GTFS Shapes To Features](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/gtfs-shapes-to-features.htm):

> Converts a GTFS shapes.txt file from a GTFS public transit dataset to
>   a polyline feature class showing the physical paths taken by vehicles
>   in the public transit system.

- [GTFS Stops To Features](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/gtfs-stops-to-features.htm):

> Converts a GTFS stop.txt file from a GTFS public transit dataset into
>   a feature class of public transit stops.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple web-based tool for converting KML files into GTFS shapes.txt files at:

http://bdferris.github.io/kml-to-gtfs-shapes/