# Generating GTFS shapes.txt?

Tags: general-transit-feed-specification

I have gtfs files from UK and I would like to know if there is a way to generate shapes.txt from these data.

I've found a tool for ArcMap, but credit is needed to use it.

Comment: What do you mean by shapes.txt?

Comment: shapes.txt is an optional file within the GTFS folder. According to GTFS reference website (https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference/shapes-file): "Shapes describe the physical path that a vehicle takes, and are defined in the file shapes.txt. Shapes belong to Trips, and consist of a sequence of points. Tracing the points in order provides the path of the vehicle. The points do not need to match stop locations."

Comment: The file is optional. There is no way to create it if it does not exist. It would be created by the transport operator to describe the path between stops. You can create your own paths, for example by just drawing between the stops, like what is done in: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49737/any-tools-to-convert-gtfs-general-transit-feed-specification-in-shp-kml?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

This tool solves the problem of generating a shapes.txt file for an existing GTFS feed based on OSM data. https://github.com/ad-freiburg/pfaedle