# Extracting Transit Layer polylines (e.g. subway lines) and using them in Google My Maps?

Tags: google-maps, polyline-creation, general-transit-feed-specification, transit

I am trying to create a Google My Map of Tokyo Metro and Toei Subway lines. So far, I've been painstakingly drawing the subway lines manually, only using a mouse. [Here's what I've got so far](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17IqsuhmIdLzkgmUrUPZ7blpmecPpfHsk&usp=sharing) (WIP, of course). It is extremely labor intensive to do it this way, and I am convinced there must be a way to automate this process, even if it requires utilizing the Google Maps API or even Google Earth Pro.

Here's another example of the kind of thing I want to do, though obviously not at this scale: https://japonyol.net/editor/ajax.html

Does Google Maps allow you to take a polyline object from the Transit Layer (e.g. the polyline of a subway line) and add the object to a Google My Map?

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49737/seeking-tool-to-convert-gtfs-general-transit-feed-specification-to-shp-kml but that does not cover the extraction of GTFS from Google.Transit

Answer (score 1):

You can convert GTFS shapes to KML: 
http://bdferris.github.io/kml-to-gtfs-shapes/

and then [load the KML](https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3024836?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) into My Maps.

Comment: The tool converts from KML *to* GTFS shapes, but what I'm looking for is the other way around--extracting the KML from the GTFS shapes

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: [Seeking tool to convert GTFS (General Transit Feed Specification) to SHP / KML?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49737/seeking-tool-to-convert-gtfs-general-transit-feed-specification-to-shp-kml)

The tool mentioned is here: http://code.google.com/p/googletransitdatafeed/wiki/KMLWriter